# SQL Conditional column and merge two rows

Tags: sql

I have found many examples of how to add conditions to the columns or how to merge with 'max' but it is not clear to me how to do it for this particular case:

SQL Query:

```
SELECT IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE, PRODUCTATTRIBUTE, VALUE
    FROM LOCKREGISTER LR
    LEFT JOIN LOCKTYPES T
        ON LR.IDLOCKTYPE = T.IDLOCKTYPE

    LEFT JOIN PRODUCTATTRIBUTES PA
        ON LR.IDPRODUCT = PA.IDPRODUCT AND (PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'CodeSet' OR PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'KeySet')

    ORDER BY IDLOCK;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do condtional aggergation :

```
SELECT IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE, 
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'CodigoConjunto' THEN  PRODUCTATTRIBUTE END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'CodigoConjunto' THEN  VALUE END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'ClaveConjunto' THEN  PRODUCTATTRIBUTE END),
       MAX(CASE WHEN PRODUCTATTRIBUTE = 'ClaveConjunto' THEN  VALUE END)
FROM LOCKREGISTER LR LEFT JOIN 
     LOCKTYPES T
     ON LR.IDLOCKTYPE = T.IDLOCKTYPE LEFT JOIN 
     PRODUCTATTRIBUTES PA
     ON LR.IDPRODUCT = PA.IDPRODUCT AND 
        PRODUCTATTRIBUTE IN ('CodigoConjunto','ClaveConjunto')
GROUP BY IDLOCK, DT, LOCKTYPE;
```

Comment: That worked like a charm, that is exactly what I was looking for (it makes sense, after all it is a mix of both concepts). Thank you so much!

Comment: I don't know why...it was not me. Thank you again for your help.